# Aggregate/ Grouping function in R with time as posixct object and multiple operations

Tags: r, aggregate

i have a problem to convert this data frame called "mergeddata" from

| time | Score | comms_num | close | volume | returns | GMEHolding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-28 10:00:00 | 795 | 63 | 335.0000 | 216927 | 0.0547 | Yes |
| 2021-01-28 10:00:00 | 250 | 16 | 335.0000 | 216927 | 0.0547 | No |
| 2021-01-28 11:00:00 | 3295 | 86 | 456.0000 | 711496 | 0.396 | No |
| 2021-01-28 11:00:00 | 561 | 86 | 456.0000 | 711496 | 0.396 | No |
| 2021-01-28 11:00:00 | 978 | 86 | 456.0000 | 711496 | 0.396 | Yes |
| 2021-01-28 11:00:00 | 3212 | 86 | 456.0000 | 711496 | 0.396 | No |
| 2021-01-28 12:00:00 | 2147 | 156 | 445.0000 | 754078 | 0.234 | No |
| 2021-01-28 12:00:00 | 39 | 66 | 445.0000 | 754078 | 0.234 | No |

to below outcome where Score, comms_num, close, volume, returns are **grouped as median** but GMEHolding is **calculated as a % ratio** of all posts within the hour.

For instance line 1 should look like this:

| time | Score | comms_num | close | volume | returns | GMEHolding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-28 10:00:00 | 795 | 63 | 335.0000 | 216927 | 0.0547 | 0.5 |
| 2021-01-28 11:00:00 | 2095 | 86 | 456.0000 | 711496 | 0.396 | 0.25 |

I tried the aggregate function but cannot differentiate the 2 operations of sum and median within it correctly. "aggregate(x = mergeddata$GMEHolding,"...

Furthermore, time is a posixct object which also seems to make things more difficult. Does anyone can help me out here?

---

```
mergeddata %>% group_by(time) %>% summarize(across(comms_num:returns, median), GMEHolding = mean(GMEHolding == "Yes"))
```

lead to this: But the first group should not return 0 for GMEHolding

[image]

Comment: `library(dplyr); mergeddata %>% group_by(time) %>% summarize(across(comms_num:returns, median), GMEHolding = mean(GMEHolding == "Yes"))`

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring! This seems almost to work. i added a screenshot of how the data looks now in the original post. The average is not calculated accurately however. For the first group it should not be 0

Comment: I don't know how to help any further without a reproducible example. It's often easiest to create those using the `dput` command, e.g. `dput(head(mergeddata, 8))` will produce code that creates an R object that is a perfect copy (data formats, structure, etc.) of the first 8 rows of your data. That will be much more helpful for others than a printout or screenshot, since we can actually run it and test on it. BTW please put the output of `dput` in the body of your question and not as a followup comment.